# Jmeter JDCB connection error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am running a query from Jmeter.

Below is my Connection string
[enter image description here][1]

Getting below error.
Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host DESKTOP-7JSVED6, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)

I opened the port 1433 at inbound rules in advanced firewall setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are totally sure you have started the SQL server and port 1433 is open in the firewall the only thing I can think of is [Enabling TCP/IP Network Protocol for SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672(v=sql.110).aspx):

1. Start SQL Server Configuration Manager. Click **Start**, point to **All Programs**, and click **Microsoft SQL Server**. Click **Configuration Tools**, and then click **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.
2. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the console pane, expand **SQL Server Network Configuration**.
3. In the console pane, click **Protocols** for .
4. In the details pane, right-click **TCP/IP**, and then click **Enable**.
5. In the console pane, click **SQL Server Services**.
6. In the details pane, right-click SQL Server (), and then click **Restart**, to stop and restart the SQL Server service.

Also double check you're using latest (or matching) [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)

More information:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)